# How do I build a Salesforce App which sends Account info to a 3rd party and displays the response in a custom component?

Tags: lightning-apps, trailhead

I am brand new to Salesforce. I need to build an app that allows me to send customer/client data to a 3rd party to be process, with the results being shown in a custom component.

I've been on a bit of a wild goose chase trying to line up the correct learning resources (Trailhead, youtube etc) in order to learn:

- how components are built
- how to link a flow to an external API
- how to customize and configure components
- basics on how to build an app

Each of the tutorials cover one aspect or another, and while things are starting to make sense its still unclear to me how to achieve my goal. More specifically, I'd like to build an external app which a user would add to their SF environement that allows me to:

option 1a) add a custom trigger to an accounts page (I know how to do this with my own components, but not sure how I'd build a 3rd party app would allow me to do this) or,

option 1b) a standalone component that is aware of which account I have selected and has a trigger that pulls the relevant info on a selected account (not sure how to do this)

2. upon initiating that trigger, send an API request (I know how to do this)
3. display the results

I'm particuarly unsure about step one. To be specific, I'd like to know:

1. Can a separate component be aware of what account is being viewed? Or do I just need that component to have its own Account selection search/dropdown feature.
2. Can a AppExchange app add custom fields/buttons/triggers to existing Salesforce pages (accounts in this instance)?

Based on the answers to the above questions, what will be incredibly helpful is links to videos/posts/tutorials/resources that walk through such examples. I'm comfortable with walking through the steps, but SF is massive and there is an overwhelming ammount of info to digest and it can get a little bit disheartening when I don't know until half way through whether a particular learning path is even going to be able to help me solve my problem.